# Query to fetch data from below table

Tags: mysql

MySQL Table information

```
emp_id   emp_name   manager_id
 1        PR          3
 2        ST          4
 3        OP          3 
 4        NP          5
 5        FGDG        12
```

Here manager_id again refers to the emp_id .
I want to find the manager name and employee name based on the emp_id in a single Query statement.

Currently i am writing 2 Queries

1. First fetching emp_name and manager_id(got emp_name)
   SELECT manager_id, emp_name FROM employee_manager WHERE emp_id = 2;
2. Based on the manger_id in above query finding manager_name
   SELECT emp_name AS Manager_name FROM employee_manager WHERE emp_id = 1;

Is it possible to write it as a single Query instead of 2 Queries?

Comment: Why is one query better? Do you know about the [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/union.html) option?

Comment: yes could you please provide appropriate idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to get the information back with a single query, on a single row. You can use a JOIN operation, and retrieve the matching row for the manager. For example:

```
SELECT e.emp_id
     , e.emp_name
     , e.manager_id
     , m.emp_id     AS manager_emp_id
     , m.emp_name   AS manager_emp_name
  FROM employee e
  LEFT
  JOIN employee m
    ON m.emd_id = e.manager_id
 WHERE e.emp_id = 4
```

Use an "outer join" operation, in case the `manager_id` column is NULL, or there isn't a row with an `emp_id` value equal to the value of the `manager_id` column. (In the example data, row with `emp_id=5` has `manager_id=12`, but we don't see a row that has `emp_id=12`. The "outer join" allows the employee row to be returned, and return NULL values for the rows for the manager. With an "inner join", we wouldn't get any row back.